# How to work with generic classes in Java?

Tags: java

I've been asked to create a generic 'Pair' class representing
the concept of "pair of meanings". Such a class turns out to be useful in
situations where you need to use two linked values. For example, in the algorithm for finding the largest element of the given array, a Pair can return the largest value itself and the value of the position (index) of the first element of the array with such value.

I could use some help here since I'm new to the concept of generics. What is wrong with the code?

```java
    public class Pair<T> {

        Integer index = 0;

        public <T extends Comparable<T> > T getLargestElement(T[] array) {
            T max = array[0]; // set first value in array as current max

             for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                 if(array[i].compareTo(max) > 0 ) {
                     max = array[i];
                     index=i;
                 }
             }// end for

             return max;
         }

         public void main(String[] args) {
             Pair<T> max = new Pair<>();
             T arr[] = new T[]{1,2,3,4,3,2,1};
             max.getLargestElement(arr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've defined two generic types (one at the class, one at the method) both named `T`. Try having just one of those. And in `main` you want `Integer` (not some generic type `T`) also you probably want to do something with the result.

Comment: I would recommend having a look at a tutorial on generics, it will give you a much better understanding that an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the actual type of `T` when using the class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pair<Integer> max = new Pair<>();
    Integer arr[] = {1,2,3,4,3,2,1};
    System.out.println(max.getLargestElement(arr)); // 4
}
```